# All text on my screen is concealed after screenshot app crashed

Tags: release-juno, screenshot

I was taking screenshots with "conceal text" enabled, And it crashed while taking a screenshot. Now all text on my screen is concealed. Even after restarting. I tried taking screenshots again with "Conceal Text" on and off, nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot is trying to tell something I can't understand]

I have no idea what the error is.